# How do I put this string with braces and brackets into a variable in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to set the following string as a variable in a bash script and am getting some errors. I assume that it is because I need to use quotations or escape it etc.

```
VARIABLENAME=$([(A"sometest",SomeOtherText "MoreText"),(A"sometext",SomeOtherText 100),(A"Sometext,SomeOtherText "SomeText")]}))
```

This doesn't work when I try to set it.

Comment: Doesn't work is not a good description. You don't email a doctor saying "I don't feel good, what should I do?". Please describe your problem more in details. For example, what error do you get? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit of a noob to bash. Also, I submitted this question prematurely, but you fixed my issue. Not sure why i didnt notice that.

Comment: If you had used an editor that uses proper highlighting, it would have been easy to spot. I actually saw it after fixing your post; stackoverflow highlighted the error for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is near the end:

```
"Sometext,
```

There is an unclosed `"`.

Answer (score 2):

The text inside `$(...)` will be interpreted as a command to run. I believe you want this instead:

```
VARIABLENAME='[(A"sometest",SomeOtherText "MoreText"),(A"sometext",SomeOtherText 100),(A"Sometext,SomeOtherText "SomeText")]})'
```

Use single quotes around your string, as it contains double quotes and does not contain any variables to expand.